# Laravel group data by odd amount of hours throughout days

Tags: php, sql, laravel, query-builder

I'm trying to group some data in my Laravel project by a date format that is a bit different to the norm. I've got a database that and a query that fetches "Uptime Checks" for a user's website based on the period they want to look over, I then need to display this to the user as some kind of timeline.

In order to reduce "noise" in the data *(where there may not be enough uptime checks for a given period)* I'd like to group all of my results within say a 3 hour period throughout the day, so I'd have all of the data for:

- 2021-05-02 03:00:00
- 2021-05-02 06:00:00
- 2021-05-02 09:00:00

and so on, right now I'm bringing back data by the hour, but not sure how to modify this to achieve the desired outcome

```php
// get the uptime checks for past X hours
$uptimeData = UptimeChecks::where('user_id', 1)
                        ->where('monitor_id', 1)
                        ->where('checked_at', '>=', '2021-05-02 13:00:00')
                        ->where('checked_at', '<=', '2021-05-03 13:00:00')
                        ->orderBy('checked_at', 'asc')
                        ->select('event', 'checked_at')
                        ->get();

$uptimeDataTimeline = $uptimeData->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
  $date = Carbon::parse($item->checked_at);

  // group by hour, how can I get say every 3 hours worth of data?
  return $date->format('Y-m-d H:00:00');
});

$uptimeDataTimeline = $uptimeDataTimeline->map(function ($checksInPeriod, $key) {
  $down = 0;
  $up = 0;
  $total = 0;
  $uptime = 0;
  $fill = '#1fc777'; // green

  // $checksInPeriod is all of the data for a given hour at the moment
  // I need to group by a bigger period, say, every 3 hours

  // add our events
  foreach ($checksInPeriod as $key => $value) {
    $total++;
    if (strtolower($value['event']) == 'down') $down++;
    if (strtolower($value['event']) == 'up') $up++;
  }

  // calculate uptime
  $uptime = floatval(number_format(round($up / $total, 5) * 100, 2, '.', ','));

  // fill colours
  if ($uptime < 100) $fill = '#9deab8'; // lighter green
  if ($uptime < 99) $fill = '#fbaa49'; // amber
  if ($uptime < 98) $fill = '#e0465e'; // red

  return [
    'total_events' => $total,
    'down_events' => $down,
    'up_events' => $up,
    'uptime' => $uptime,
    'fill' => $fill
  ];
});
```

Not sure how to modify the `groupBy` function which returns the format since my understanding is that it's not possible to do that? I'm using Carbon by the way.

#### Update

I've been digging, and have come across the `CarbonInterval` feature, which allows me to generate some intervals, and I've tried implementing this, I seem to get an equally spaced time period, but my data is out and doesn't contain all of the data between two intervals (see attached image)

```php
$intervals = CarbonInterval::hours(2)->toPeriod($from, $to);

$uptimeDataTimeline = $uptimeData->groupBy(function ($item, $key) use ($intervals) {
  $date = Carbon::parse($item->checked_at);

  foreach ($intervals as $key => $interval) {
    if ($date->hour == Carbon::parse($interval)->addHours(1)->hour) {
      $actualHour1 = Carbon::parse($interval)->hour;
      if (strlen($actualHour1) == 1) $actualHour1 = "0$actualHour1";
      return $date->format("Y-m-d $actualHour1:00:00");
    } else if ($date->hour == Carbon::parse($interval)->addHours(2)->hour) {
      $actualHour2 = Carbon::parse($interval)->subHours(2)->hour;
      if (strlen($actualHour2) == 1) $actualHour2 = "0$actualHour2";
      return $date->format("Y-m-d $actualHour2:00:00");
    }
  }

  return $date->format('Y-m-d H:00:00');
});
```

For instance, I should be seeing all of the checks for the hours 7 and 8 within the `07` key, but instead I'm seeing data for just one hour (hour `11`)?

[image]

Comment: So you want to have 8 partitions of 3 hours each?

Comment: That's correct yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to use whenever you need time slice(s) is DateInterval or better CarbonInterval. What they give you is the ability to loop over those slices and do equality/unequlity operation of your sample data this way you can easily organise your data by those time slices to their respective "slots"

Here is an general idea on how to

```
$intervals = \Carbon\CarbonInterval::hours(3)->toPeriod('2021-05-02 13:00:00', '2021-05-03 13:00:00'); 
//we get time slots of 3 hours between provided datetimes

foreach ($intervals as $date) {
    $dtArr[] = strtotime($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')); //we collect those "time markers"
}

$result = [
    'first'=> 0,
    'second'=>0.
    'third'=>0,
    'forth'=>0,
    'fifth'=>0,
    'sixth'=>0,
    'seventh'=>0,
    'eighth'=>0
]; //array to accumulate your aggregations to correct time slot

foreach ($uptimeData as $sample) {
    //loop over sample set
    $ordinality = getSlotNo($sample->checked_at); //eg. third
    //read the accumulated total in $result and add this too
    $result[$ordinality] += 1;
}


function getSlotNo($dt){
    $ts = strtotime($dt);
    
    //eg. say greater than or equal to "13:00" but smaller than "16:00" -> You go in first slot
    if($ts>=$dtArr[0] && $ts<$dtArr[1]){
        //first slot
        return 'first';
    }
    elseif($ts>=$dtArr[1] && $ts<$dtArr[2]){
     //eg. say greater than or equal to "16:00" but smaller than "19:00" -> You go in second slot
        //second slot
        return 'second';
    }
    elseif($ts>=$dtArr[2] && $ts<$dtArr[3]){
        //third slot
        return 'third';
    }

    // and so on
}
```

**UPDATE**

Try something like this may be, modify the slot getter to "look ahead" and decide the result

```
$i=0;
foreach ($intervals as $date) {
    $dtArr[] = strtotime($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')); //we collect those "time markers"
    $result['int_'.$i] = 0;
    $i++;
}

//fake data
$uptimeData=collect([
    (object)['checked_at'=>'2021-05-03 10:10:00'],
    (object)['checked_at'=>'2021-05-03 11:20:00'],
    (object)['checked_at'=>'2021-05-03 12:20:00'],
    (object)['checked_at'=>'2021-05-03 13:20:00'],
    (object)['checked_at'=>'2021-05-03 14:20:00'],
]);

foreach ($uptimeData as $sample) {
    //loop over sample set
    $ordinalInfo = getSlotNo($sample->checked_at, $dtArr); //eg. third
    //read the accumulated total in $result and add this too
    if($ordinalInfo['match']){
        $result['int_'.$ordinalInfo['index']] += 1;
    }
}

/**
* @param $dt 
* @return int index in $dtArr this value belongs to
*/
function getSlotNo($dt, $dtArr){
    $ts = strtotime($dt);
    $info = [];

    for($i =0; $i<count($dtArr); $i++){

        if(!empty($dtArr[$i+1])){ // if not reached the last item ie. still there's a next
            if($ts>=$dtArr[$i] && $ts<$dtArr[$i+1]){
                //i'th slot
                $info=['match'=>true,'index'=>$i];
                break;
            }
        }else{
            // at last item ie. ( $i == count($dtArr)-1 )
            if($ts<=$dtArr[$i])
                $info=['match'=>true,'index'=>$i];
            else
                $info=['match'=>false,'index'=>NULL];

        }

    }
    return $info;
}
```

Comment: This is great, is there a more "automated" way of having that `getSlotNo` function being built without defining the individual ones inside? If there's no data beyond a period, then one would fail for instance

Comment: If you mean avoiding hand-coding if-else structures then may be you can checkout the updated code

Comment: I've updated my post's description with some new code and a screenshot since using part of your suggestion I've achieved a bit more, maybe my update in the description will provide a bit more insight since my data is off :(

Comment: Sorry for replying late, in that case you may collect all the sample points in one flat master array and sort it by `checked_at`